# Flex URLLoader.close() doesn't abort upload / load

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

Ran into a weird Flex bug (i guess) ... I am uploading using URurlLoader.load(urlRequest) ... on cancel button click, urlLoader.close() is called.. but this doesnt abort the upload the file shows up on the server.

Is this a Flex bug or am I missing something? Can anybody confirm if they have been able to abort an upload / load with the urlLoader.close() method call?

-- Sri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `URLLoader.close` method only terminates the loading of incoming data to Flash. It cannot abort any processing/loading being done on the server side.

You might want to look into using the `FileReference.upload` method. That can be canceled mid-upload.

Comment: I cannot use FileReference.upload because I compress the ByteArray on the Flex client and I need to upload this compressed Byte Array. I hoped urlLoader.close() would abort the urlLoader.load() method that is uploading the file.